# SQL field does not have a default value - Even though field is set to default NULL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have an older SQL database that I am trying to use, I am not sure of the version it was originally built for but I am trying to use it with `Maria 10.2`

`table1` looks like this...

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I am trying to write a firstname to it with a prepared statement like this...

```
$query = $this->sql->prepare("
   INSERT INTO `table1` (`firstname`)
   VALUES (?)
");

$query->bind_param("s",'john');
```

I am getting an SQL error.....

```
[error] => Field 'lastname' doesn't have a default value
```

Where am I going wrong? It looks like default is set to `NULL` so doesn't need me to explicitly set a value.

I have also seen mention of strict_trans_tables being an issue with newer versions but can't see why this would apply here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your default value is NULL, the column `NULL` is set to `NO`.

Try

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY `lastname` varchar(255) null;
```